# Is there a good way to get Context when I use Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I hope to get `Context` in `@Composable` function, but Code A is wrong.

At present, I have to use Code B to get Context.

I think Code B is not good, is there other way to get `Context in` @Composable `function ?`

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun RecordTitleWithToolBar(){   
      
        IconButton(
            onClick = {
                LocalContext.current.toast(R.string.suggest_share_app)
            }
        ) {

        }
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun RecordTitleWithToolBar(){   

        val context= LocalContext.current

        IconButton(           
            onClick = {
                context.toast(R.string.suggest_share_app)             
            }
        ) {
            
        }

}
```

Comment: Code B is the way to do it. Android calls context that way in all of their code examples https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#call-view https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal#intro https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#deeplinks

Comment: What do you mean by "a good way"? And why exactly do you think "code B is not good"?

Comment: Thanks! I expect that there is a  `context`  variable I can access it inside @Composable function freely, such as `LocalContext.current`, unfortunately it is not available in `onClick = { ...}` which is wrapped in a  @Composable function .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LocalContext](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary#LocalContext()) uses [CompositionLocal](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal) to pass context implicitly.

If we check the `onClick()` definition for any Material Button, we can see that the methods do not have Composable context scope. So we cannot use composable functions in non-composable scope.

> In other words code B is the correct one

Comment: In another words code B is correct one 

Comment: Thanks! I expect that there is a  `context`  variable I can access it inside @Composable function freely, such as `LocalContext.current`, unfortunately it is not available in `onClick = { ...}` which is wrapped in a  @Composable function .

Comment: Even though `onClick()` is inside a Composable function, the code inside `onClick` does not have composable scope. This is similar to `LazyRow` or `LazyColumn`. Only `items` or `item` provides the composable scope in them.